# Can I save my game locally?

Tags: simcity-2013

I read in an article dating from December that SimCity games would be saved *online*. I have not yet bought the game, and I wonder if this is true. It would be bad enough to be forced out of the game if my connection is lost, but I would be edgy to not be able to save my game after I notice a lost connection, as I am pretty bad at saving regularly and would hate to lose my whole session after being kicked out.

So, is the game really saved online? If so, is there a way to have some kind of backup on my computer? I suppose it wouldn't be so bad if there was an auto-save thing. Is there?

Comment: I would imagine it would be at least cached locally. When you upload a video stream, it is still cached first on your local pc, before it's uploaded. Same concept here :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does it automatically. I have not yet dealt with the connection drops on my ISP’s end, but I was disconnected several times from the server, and when I returned, I hadn’t miss a beat. One time it actually gave me the message that the game was saved locally, and would be synchronized once it is connected again.

This feature removes headache of saving (or neglecting to do so), but removes the ability of save/load trial and error, forcing you to think before you plot.

Comment: It's also forces you to be online to load your save, which is a major complaint and PITA as well.

Comment: I've never had one of my cities save locally when disconnected from the server. My progress is always lost. I hope they fix this soon.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini, you should contact tech support. I get disconnect notifications (top left corner) quite often, and was dropped out three or four times, including that one time when I got synchronisation message. But all this time my cities saved fine.

Comment: I'll wait a few days. I think their support is busy right now ;)